# How do I initialize canvas in android studio?

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle on an existing class. A lot of the tutorials that I've seen create a new class. However, I get an error that says that the canvas was not initialized. How do I initialize the canvas? Thanks

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Context context;
    Canvas canvas;
    Rect ourRect = new Rect();
    ourRect.set(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight()/2);

    Paint blue = new Paint();
    blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    canvas.drawRect(ourRect,blue);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the canvas variable as follows

```
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
```